# problem with for loop over array inside trigger function

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, triggers

I'm trying to put a trigger on a table. This table has a body column with type text. The text in this column can contain @{username} mentions and I need to extract them and write them to the database and also notify my application.

The code below works, but I don't think its ideal that in the foreach block, I'm doing an extra select to get the user_id of associated with the username. But the problem is, I can't figure out how to foreach over the mentions json as an array. I've tried many things but I just got error after error, and quite frankly I have a headache now!

It also seems weird to me that I have to have the usernames array just to extract the usernames and then put id,username,firebase_id in another array but I couldn't select both the result of parse_tokens and the id, firebase_id from the users table to a single array.

Any ideas?
Any other suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

```sql
create or replace function notif() returns trigger as $$
  declare
    usernames text[];
    mentions json;
    mu text;
  begin
    select parse_tokens(new.body, '@') into usernames;
    select json_agg(tmp)
      from (
        select id, username, firebase_id
        into mentions
        from users
        where username=any(usernames)
      ) tmp;

    perform pg_notify('status', mentions::text);

    foreach mu in array usernames loop
      insert into mentions (status_id, from_user_id, to_user_id) values
        (new.id, new.user_id, (select id from users where username=mu));
    end loop;

    return new;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can you supply the table and trigger definition? I'm assuming this is a trigger on the users table. If the users table contains the `body` and `id` field you can do it all at once.

Comment: No, Its a trigger on the table for status updates.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved the problem. This does exactly what I want:

```sql
create type mention_info as (id integer, username varchar(64), firebase_id varchar(64));

create or replace function notif() returns trigger as $$
  declare
    mentions mention_info[];
    m mention_info;
  begin
    select array_agg(tmp) into mentions from 
      (select id, username, firebase_id from users
        where username=any(parse_tokens(new.body, '@'))) tmp;

    perform pg_notify('status', mentions::text);
    foreach m in array mentions loop
      insert into mentions
        (status_id, from_user_id, to_user_id) values (new.id, new.user_id, m.id);
    end loop;

    return new;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```